# Java splitting nested brackets string

Tags: java, regex, oop, extract

I have a string like:

```
Fields  { name:"aa" type: "bb" paramA { name:"cc" } paramB { other:"ee" other_p:"ff"} paramC { name: "bb" param: "dd" other_params { abc: "xx" xyz:"yy"}} }
```

My regex code in Java extract all that is between brackets for paramA, paramB and other_params. I need somehow to structure this in a Java object, but I am stucked at paramC extraction.

```
Pattern pattern=Pattern.compile("\\w+\\s(\\{([^{]*?)\\})");
Matcher matcher=pattern.matcher(theAboveString);
while (matcher.find()){
System.out.println(matcher.group(1);
}
```

My code for the extraction

Comment: No no no no no no no no no. Use a JSON parser like [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson).

Comment: No need to reinvent the wheel. Use a JSON library

Comment: But it is not a JSON object.

Comment: It's looking like one

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java

Comment: It is a file obtained from a C program. I need to change it using a graphic tool in Java.. So I need to do an import and than an export after modifying it. But definitely is not a JSON file

Comment: For all the JSON commenters, please notice that it's missing the commas between the values and `paramA` doesn't end with a colon, so *it's not JSON*.

Comment: Even if it's not valid JSON, it's still some form of markup. Regex out. You're better off implementing your own parser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of parsing using regex:

```
String input = "Fields  { name:\"aa\" type: \"bb\" paramA { name:\"cc\" } paramB { other:\"ee\" other_p:\"ff\"} paramC { name: \"bb\" param: \"dd\" other_params { abc: \"xx\" xyz:\"yy\"}} }";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\s*(?:(\\w+)\\s*(?::\\s*(\".*?\")|\\{)|\\})\\s*").matcher(input);
int start = 0;
Deque<String> stack = new ArrayDeque<>();
while (m.find()) {
    if (m.start() != start)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid data at " + start);
    if (m.group(2) != null) {
        System.out.println(stack + " : " + m.group(1) + " = " + m.group(2));
    } else if (m.group(1) != null) {
        //System.out.println(m.group(1) + " {");
        stack.addLast(m.group(1));
    } else {
        //System.out.println("}");
        if (stack.isEmpty())
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unbalanced brace at " + start);
        stack.removeLast();
    }
    start = m.end();
}
if (start != input.length())
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid data at " + start);
if (! stack.isEmpty())
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unexpected end of text");
```

*Output*

```
[Fields] : name = "aa"
[Fields] : type = "bb"
[Fields, paramA] : name = "cc"
[Fields, paramB] : other = "ee"
[Fields, paramB] : other_p = "ff"
[Fields, paramC] : name = "bb"
[Fields, paramC] : param = "dd"
[Fields, paramC, other_params] : abc = "xx"
[Fields, paramC, other_params] : xyz = "yy"
```

You should be able to take it from here.

**UPDATE**

To also support numeric values, use this regex:

```
"\\s*(?:(\\w+)\\s*(?::\\s*(\".*?\"|[-+0-9.eE]+)|\\{)|\\})\\s*"
```

Testing with `"Layer { name: \"conv2\" type: \"Convolution\" bottom: \"norm1\" top: \"conv2\" param { lr_mult: 1 decay_mult: 1 } param { lr_mult: 2 decay_mult: 0 } convolution_param { num_output: 256 pad: 2 kernel_size: 5 group: 2 weight_filler { type: \"gaussian\" std: 0.01 } bias_filler { type: \"constant\" value: 1 } }}"` produces:

```
[Layer] : name = "conv2"
[Layer] : type = "Convolution"
[Layer] : bottom = "norm1"
[Layer] : top = "conv2"
[Layer, param] : lr_mult = 1
[Layer, param] : decay_mult = 1
[Layer, param] : lr_mult = 2
[Layer, param] : decay_mult = 0
[Layer, convolution_param] : num_output = 256
[Layer, convolution_param] : pad = 2
[Layer, convolution_param] : kernel_size = 5
[Layer, convolution_param] : group = 2
[Layer, convolution_param, weight_filler] : type = "gaussian"
[Layer, convolution_param, weight_filler] : std = 0.01
[Layer, convolution_param, bias_filler] : type = "constant"
[Layer, convolution_param, bias_filler] : value = 1
```

Comment: That's a great solution. I have only one more problem. The iput field may be something like: Fields  { name:"aa" type: "bb" paramA { name:"cc" } paramB { other:"ee" other_p:"ff"} }. In this case should I have a different Regex for each different String or type of Field?

Comment: Sorry for bothering you. I tried the code but the following string it does not work. I tried to change the Regex but with no succes to have good results for the following:  "Layer  {   name: \"conv2\"  type: \"Convolution\"  bottom: \"norm1\"  top: \"conv2\"  param {    lr_mult: 1    decay_mult: 1  }   param {    lr_mult: 2    decay_mult: 0  } convolution_param {    num_output: 256    pad: 2    kernel_size: 5    group: 2    weight_filler {      type: \"gaussian\"      std: 0.01    }    bias_filler {      type: \"constant\"      value: 1    }  }}" . Can you please have a look?

Comment: I used this regex: Matcher m=Pattern.compile("\\s*(?:(\\w+)\\s*(?::\\s*((\".*?\")|(\\s*\\d+\\s*)|(\\s*\\w+\\s*))|\\{)|\\})\\s*").matcher(layer);

Comment: It works also for numbers but I get as output the following: [Layer] : name = "conv1"
[Layer] : type = "Convolution"
[Layer] : bottom = "data"
[Layer] : top = "conv1"
[Layer, param] : lr_mult = 1    
[Layer, param] : decay_mult = 1  
[Layer, param] : lr_mult = 2    
[Layer, param] : decay_mult = 0  
[Layer, convolution_param] : num_output = 96    
[Layer, convolution_param] : kernel_size = 11    
[Layer, convolution_param] : stride = 4    
[Layer, convolution_param, weight_filler] : type = "gaussian"
[Layer, convolution_param, weight_filler] : std = 0. Don't know where the error is

Comment: Use this: `"\\s*(?:(\\w+)\\s*(?::\\s*(\".*?\"|[-+0-9.eE]+)|\\{)|\\})\\s*"`

Comment: It does not work better than mine: It extracts only  ` [Layer] : name = "data"
[Layer] : type = "Data"
[Layer] : top = "data"
[Layer] : top = "label"`

Comment: With mine:`"\\s*(?:(\\w+)\\s*(?::\\s*((\".*?\")|(\\s*\\d+\\s*)|(\\s*\\w+\\s*))|\\{)|‌​\\})\\s*"` I get: [Layer] : name = "conv1"
[Layer] : type = "Convolution"
[Layer] : bottom = "data"
[Layer] : top = "conv1"
[Layer, param] : lr_mult = 1    
[Layer, param] : decay_mult = 1  
[Layer, param] : lr_mult = 2    
[Layer, param] : decay_mult = 0  
[Layer, convolution_param] : num_output = 96    
[Layer, convolution_param] : kernel_size = 11    
[Layer, convolution_param] : stride = 4    
[Layer, convolution_param, weight_filler] : type = "gaussian"
[Layer, convolution_param, weight_filler] : std = 0

Comment: I just ran it with that `"Layer { ..."` string, and it worked fine with the regex I just gave.

Comment: One more question: why when I print the stack outside the while it is empty?

Comment: Because it has to be, see last `if` statement. The values are removed from the stack when an end-brace (`}`) is processed. If the stack isn't empty when done, it means that end-braces are missing.

Comment: I succeed in the end to parse all and to modify the values for the attributes. Now the question is how I can write the deque to the file to have the same file format?

Comment: @AmridaD That sounds like something you should ask in a new question.

Comment: Ok Andreas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34318327/java-parsing-string-read-write-to-file

Answer (score 2):

You can't parse infinitely nest-able nodes with regex. (See Chomsky's categorization of languages/automatons, or any stackoverflow question about parsing HTML with regex.)

I've made a library that let's you parse things like this. It even has proper documentation.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/jparser2/

Documentation:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/jparser2/files/doc/